# compact framework 3.5 application wont run on windows mobile 6.1

Tags: compact-framework, smartphone

however can get compact framework 2.0 program to run.

compact 3.5 is installed on phone???

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that all Windows Mobile 6.1 phones come with 3.5 version preinstalled. You can detect which version of the compact framework is installed by reading a registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework
```

Answer (score 1):

CF 3.5 was an *option* for OEMs to install, not a requirement, so it's probably not on your phone.  Run cgacutil.exe in the \Windows folder to get it to report all of the versions installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone doesn't have NETCF 3.5, this Microsoft web page says (I think) you can install NETCF 3.5 on your WM6 device:

[NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en)

(Your question is very unclear; I'm not sure if you're saying the device already has NETCF 3.5 installed, or you are asking if it is.)